# For the label widget, is that possible to change the text alignment

Tags: dm-script

I used DLGCreateLabel("test", 20).Anchor("East") to create a label, and would like to make the text align right. But it doesn't work. Is there any attribute of label to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to right-justify text within the label field, itself. However, you may want to try rendering the label without any space to the right (i.e. leave out the minimum length parameter, the value 20 in your case) and then place the label to the right side of an enclosing panel or table column by using the Anchor("East") call. You may need to use DLGExpand("X") and/or DLGFill("X") calls to make sure the enclosing panel or table makes full use of available horizontal space when placing the label.